# Pseudo Terminal Setup Error ErrorCode: 7 Errno: 6 when trying to build and launch a Swift app on Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios16

I am getting the error below when I try to launch my application on XCode via the iPhone 12 Pro simulator.

[image]

The full logs are

```
Details

Pseudo Terminal Setup Error
Domain: IDEPseudoTerminalDomain
Code: 7
Failure Reason: ErrorCode: 7 Errno: 6
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-05-17 14:05:21 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. Device not configured
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 6
Failure Reason: Device not configured
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone13,3";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.4 (20E247)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 50;
    "operation_errorCode" = 7;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDEPseudoTerminalDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator16.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.3.1 (Build 22E261)
Xcode 14.3 (21812) (Build 14E222b)
Timestamp: 2023-05-17T22:05:21+08:00
```

I have tried restarting my XCode multiple times, clearing the cache, trying other simulators but I am still getting the same error.
The specs I am using are:
XCode ver 14.3
MacOS 13.3.1 (22E261)
Simulator IOS 16

I have tried restarting my XCode multiple times, clearing the cache, trying other simulators but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Like the poster, I hit this hideously annoying issue.  Likewise, clearing, restarting Xcode, rebooting and the issue persisted.  Could not run ANY app from Xcode.  Some older references to the same issue, hinted at errant, unterminated processes.  Doing a ps -ef showed a large number of processes running (not wholly unexpected).  Being suspicious of some process (yes, I am looking at you goolge chrome helper) I rebooted AND unchecked the "reopen windows" option, which I normally use.  The number of running processes dropped significantly and Xcode was back to normal.  So, I cannot identify any root cause, but this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem today an here is the trick that helped me.
Just make sure to close Xcode and the simulator wenn you want to move to another project. you should close this Apps like usually (by hitting the red button on top left) and end the program (by hitting the icon of Xcode in "the Dock" and the button command at the same time and then select "end". You have to do it as well for the simulator). After that, your should no longer appear.

NB: Down at the bottom of the Mac's screen is a quick access tool bar called "the Dock."

Answer (score 0):

Got this as well - try closing Xcode, Simulator (make sure not running in background) and Terminal (which will show the crash) - then open Terminal and sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

Select an iPhone type in simulator when this runs (mine was cleared)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same thing, and restarting XCode didn't help. So I just rebooted my machine and now it's running normally.

Didn't need to do anything beyond that.